# datepicker undefined is not a function

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I am making an app in asp.net and I am using DataList. I want to add datepicker (jquery) in my app. I have created MasterPage2 and added javascripts and css

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/layout-admin.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery-ui.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
    <script src="js/jquery-1.10.2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery-ui.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery-1.5.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <script src="js/hideshow.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.tablesorter.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.equalHeight.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
                $(function () {
                    $("#txtData").datepicker({
                        showButtonPanel: true
                    });
                });
            $(".tablesorter").tablesorter();
        });
```

and from AddArtikulli.aspx

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="AddArtikull.aspx.cs" Inherits="AddArticle" MasterPageFile="~/MasterPage2.master" %>
 <asp:Label ID="lblData" runat="server" style="font-weight: 700">Data e Publikimit</asp:Label>
                <fieldset>
                    <asp:TextBox  ID="txtData" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>                   
                </fieldset>
```

It shows this error in console:

> Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function

Comment: make sure to select datepicker while download jquery from download builder http://jqueryui.com/download/ maybe you forgot to check it or try to copy stylesheet and script from demo http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/

Answer (score 3):

You are including jQuery again after jQuery UI so every plugin bound to jQuery, and $ alias too (like jQuery UI) will be deleted.

Remove the second jQuery core include:

```
<script src="js/jquery-1.5.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

you don't need to include jQuery more times.

Comment: now it doesn't shows any error, but neither datepicker

Comment: I would suggest either starting from scratch or sending us a js fiddle with that you have so far.  I was able to fix my situation by copying from an old _Layout.cshtml that worked, but I'm still not sure what the difference was in my situation.

Answer (score 0):

Use fiddler or similar tool to make sure your scripts are loading correctly. This is correct to remove doubled scripts. Also take a look at bootstrap there you can find datepickre control.

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem in my MVC web application and resolve it after found that $("#txtData").datepicker() is executed before jquery and jquery ui scripts are loaded.

I was using $("#txtData").datepicker() in partial view used as template for Date.
And found that my upper level view  which uses this partial view has scripts section at the end of document.

I have moved this script into scripts section of my view and put it after loading jquery bundle:
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
$("#txtData").datepicker()

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
   $("#<%= txtData.ClientID %>").datepicker({
             showButtonPanel: true
   });
   $(".tablesorter").tablesorter();
});
```

You have to add **'ClientID'** to your textbox id selector because TextBox is server control. Also remove any one version of jquery library.

Answer (score 0):

If you are absolutley sure that your $("#div-id") is defined, i.e., it has a value that is something like [...], then it might mean that you have some conflicting jquery.

Try adding this to your code when the page loads:

$.noConflict(true);